# when i try to build my project i get this error

Tags: reactjs, cmd, next.js, graphql, vercel

I don't know how to solve

when i try to bild on vercel the project, i get this error :

```
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated acorn-dynamic-import@2.0.2: This is probably built in to whatever tool you're using. If you still need it... idk
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
```

this is the error that appears when i try to upload it

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /category/[slug]: /category/sport
    /posts/[slug]: /posts/che-te-guardi-ah-oh
    /posts/[slug]: /posts/chi-fa-sport-e-omosessuale
    /posts/[slug]: /posts/come-fossero-i-giocatori-senza-denti
    /posts/[slug]: /posts/e-se-il-sium-non-esistesse
    /posts/[slug]: /posts/fabio-rovazzi-esiste-nel-nostro-universo
    /posts/[slug]: /posts/la-terra-e-piatta-basta-dire-cazzate
    /posts/[slug]: /posts/lo-sport-serve-davvero
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:409:19
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1345:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1205:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:66:29)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Comment: There is no error in the code snippet

Comment: This is only warnings here i do not see any errors.

Comment: suspect these were the errors that prevented me from compiling the project, the other error it gives me is too many requests to the database(error429), but I don't think it has anything to do with the project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425601/next-js-build-failing-due-to-export-encountered-errors-on-following-paths